# Why is WPF ComboBox styling not as expected?

Tags: wpf, combobox, styling

I have a WPF app with a ComboBox where I want to style the items but get an unexpected behaviour depending upon which item is selected.

The following XAML snippet demonstrates the problem:

```cs
<Page
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
  <Page.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="ItemStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="Content" Value="ABC">
                <Setter Property="FontStyle" Value="Oblique"/>
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="BoxStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="Text" Value="ABC">
                <Setter Property="FontStyle" Value="Italic"/>
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
  </Page.Resources>
  <Border Width="200">  
      <ComboBox Style="{StaticResource BoxStyle}"
                ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ItemStyle}"
                Height="20">
          <ComboBoxItem>ABC</ComboBoxItem>
          <ComboBoxItem>DEF</ComboBoxItem>
          <ComboBoxItem>GHI</ComboBoxItem>
      </ComboBox>
  </Border>
</Page>
```

This displays a simple ComboBox with three items; ABC, DEF and GHI. Note that ABC is shown in the dropdown with oblique, red text and also in the selection box when selected.

However, if I then open the dropdown again all 3 items are shown oblique and red.

If the DEF or GHI items are selected then these show in normal font, black and on opening the dropdown again show correctly - with ABC still showing oblique, red.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of [Dependency Property Value Precedence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230.aspx). When ABC is selected the `ComboBoxItem`s in the DropDown inherit the `FontStyle` and `Foreground` from the `ComboBox`.

This will fix the code as the `ComboBoxItem`s won't inherit FontStyle and Foreground from the ComboBox:

```
    <Page.Resources>
            <Style x:Key="ItemStyle"
                   TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
                <Setter Property="FontStyle"
                        Value="Normal" />
                <Setter Property="Foreground"
                        Value="Black" />
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="Content"
                             Value="ABC">
                        <Setter Property="FontStyle"
                                Value="Oblique" />
                        <Setter Property="Foreground"
                                Value="Red" />
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
            <Style x:Key="BoxStyle"
                   TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="Text"
                             Value="ABC">
                        <Setter Property="FontStyle"
                                Value="Italic" />
                        <Setter Property="Foreground"
                                Value="Red" />
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Page.Resources>
        <Border Width="200">
            <ComboBox Style="{StaticResource BoxStyle}"
                      ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ItemStyle}"
                      Height="20">
                <ComboBoxItem>ABC</ComboBoxItem>
                <ComboBoxItem>DEF</ComboBoxItem>
                <ComboBoxItem>GHI</ComboBoxItem>
            </ComboBox>
        </Border>
```